# Refactoring resources from activities issues

Tags: android, android-layout

I wanted to refactor the source code of my project into different modules. Two of those modules are **app** and **resources**. I have the following layout file under the resource module:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.DrawerActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_drawer" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Now, my issue is with the **tools:context** attribute. It does not longer find the DrawerActivity class. What is the new path to this class? I've tried:

- app.src.main.java.com.company.project.activities.DrawerActivity
- com.company.project.activities.DrawerActivity
- .activities.DrawerActivity

The AndroidManifest file under the resources module is as follows (yes it is this small):

```
<manifest package="com.company.resources" />
```

Is it even possible to split up the resources and the activities into separate modules? I'm asking since the attribute **tools:showIn** does not seem to render anymore.

Update 1: Added screenshot as requested...
[image]

UPDATE 1:

If I let the package to be the same for both AndroidManifest files (app and resources modules), then the **.activities.** part of the path will become green (stated under the layout file). The DrawerActivity name will however still remain red. How come?

Comment: can you post a screenshot of your application folder/module layout?

Comment: @KaranHarshWardhan : Here you go...